# How to send mouse clicks?

Tags: python, windows, mouseevent, ctypes

I have the code below. I can use it to send keyboard keys but I can't figure how to use it to send mouse clicks:

```
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
INPUT_MOUSE    = 0
INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
INPUT_HARDWARE = 2
KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001
KEYEVENTF_KEYUP       = 0x0002
KEYEVENTF_UNICODE     = 0x0004
KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE    = 0x0008
MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0
wintypes.ULONG_PTR = wintypes.WPARAM

class MOUSEINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("dx",          wintypes.LONG),
                ("dy",          wintypes.LONG),
                ("mouseData",   wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwFlags",     wintypes.DWORD),
                ("time",        wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", wintypes.ULONG_PTR))

class KEYBDINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("wVk",         wintypes.WORD),
                ("wScan",       wintypes.WORD),
                ("dwFlags",     wintypes.DWORD),
                ("time",        wintypes.DWORD),
                ("dwExtraInfo", wintypes.ULONG_PTR))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(KEYBDINPUT, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        # some programs use the scan code even if KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE
        # isn't set in dwFflags, so attempt to map the correct code.
        if not self.dwFlags & KEYEVENTF_UNICODE:
            self.wScan = user32.MapVirtualKeyExW(self.wVk,
                                                 MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, 0)

class HARDWAREINPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("uMsg",    wintypes.DWORD),
                ("wParamL", wintypes.WORD),
                ("wParamH", wintypes.WORD))

class INPUT(ctypes.Structure):
    class _INPUT(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = (("ki", KEYBDINPUT),
                    ("mi", MOUSEINPUT),
                    ("hi", HARDWAREINPUT))
    _anonymous_ = ("_input",)
    _fields_ = (("type",   wintypes.DWORD),
                ("_input", _INPUT))

LPINPUT = ctypes.POINTER(INPUT)

def _check_count(result, func, args):
    if result == 0:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

user32.SendInput.errcheck = _check_count
user32.SendInput.argtypes = (wintypes.UINT, # nInputs
                             LPINPUT,       # pInputs
                             ctypes.c_int)  # cbSize

def Press(hexKeyCode):
    hexKeyCode = VK_CODE.get(hexKeyCode)
    x = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
              ki=KEYBDINPUT(wVk=hexKeyCode))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    x = INPUT(type=INPUT_KEYBOARD,
              ki=KEYBDINPUT(wVk=hexKeyCode,
                            dwFlags=KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))
```

I am trying to send mouse clicks to my game.
I tried a lot of libraries to do that (pyaitogui, autoit, win32, wincon, pyinput, mouse, etc.).
They just don't work with that game, but for some reason using the code above I could successfully send keyboard strikes to the game but I can't figure how to use the `MOUSEINPUT` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This additional code to your attempt worked for me once I added missing imports and commented out the missing `VK_CODE` (FYI, make sure your code example works without changes).  The field values are described in the MSDN [MOUSEINPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-mouseinput) documentation.

```py
MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002
MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004

def Mouse(dx, dy, flags):
    x = INPUT(type=INPUT_MOUSE, mi=MOUSEINPUT(dx, dy, 0, flags, 0, 0))
    user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.sizeof(INPUT))

Mouse(0, 0, MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN)
Mouse(200, 200, MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE)
Mouse(0, 0, MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP)
```

Comment: the mouse event left down and up works perfectly.

Comment: tyhe move event doesnt move to the right coordinates tried this to calculate it but doesnt work either:
dx = int(65536 * dx / ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) + 1)
dy = int(65536 * dy / ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) + 1)

Comment: i used pyautogui.moveTo(x, y) and it works as a temporarly solution but idlike to know what am doing wrong for future improvment.

Comment: alright i figure it out, you just move the mouse from the current mouse position by dx dy,

Comment: so if you are in coordinate (100, 200)
and u canll Mouse(50, 50, MOUSEEVENT_MOVE)
it will moves the mouse to coordinates ( 150, 250).
thank you verymuch for the help

Comment: @AkaliDZ see the MOUSEINPUT link in my answer. You can move to an absolute position with the appropriate flags.